# Upload a file from a remote computer fail for file over 3MB

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I created a ASP.net website and is already uploaded to IIS. I can access it from an outside network.

I was testing the upload function. It was uploading files, but when I tried to upload a file of 4.09MB it took 40 seconds for upload. However, the file did not upload and give an 'Server Error'.

I tried to increase the connection timeout in the connection string to 600. Also, I see that the file is uploading in a corner of the website (Google Chrome browser) and when it said 99% then the error occur.

Using my local connection do not give any error.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=uploading+large+files+to+an+asp.net+server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try extending the maxRequestLength in the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="12288" />
```

The default maximum is 4MB so needs extending for files more than that.